# Python: Using .join to concatenate items in a list of strings within an enumerate for loop and receiving an unexpected output

Tags: python, scope

Main Problem: I cant figure out why output file is not writing verses 1:6 and 1:23. I want to figure out why this is and how to fix it.

I'm new to python and don't quite understand if it's my logic or a misunderstanding of how things work in python that's leading me astray. I am Using .join to concatenate items in a list of strings within an enumerate for loop and receiving an unexpected output. Specifically, I am using python to parse a .txt file. The .txt file contains data on words in the bible. I want the new output.txt to read such that new bible verses coincide with new lines. Problem is, the python script I wrote is completely skipping over verse 6 and verse 23 on the test data output. I suspect it has something to do with how I'm using .join in parallel with the for loop and my lack of understanding how this works in python. However, it could also just be that I understand but committed a logical error. Here is my code. Note the debug statements, the .join I use in the functions I defined and how this would affect the strings I am parsing in the outer for loop ("where I think my error is at but I could be wrong").

```
def concatenateNext_string_TF( index, lines_list):
    next_wL_index = index + 1
    if next_wL_index < len(lines_list):
        #ThisIs A variable word_list: tric for splitin a string to a list of words
        problem_var = lines_list[next_wL_index]
        problem_words2 = problem_var.split()
        #Check if this is a vere or a glitch where we start in middle of verse
        if ( (problem_words2[0].isdigit() < 8) and (':' not in problem_words2[0]) ):
            return True

    return False

    #DEBUG: condition_String, real_index
def concatenateNext_string( index, lines_list, condition_String, real_index):
    next_wL_index = index + 1
    if next_wL_index < len(lines_list):
        #ThisIs A variable word_list: tric for splitin a string to a list of words
        problem_var = lines_list[next_wL_index]
        problem_words2 = problem_var.split()

        if ( (problem_words2[0].isdigit() < 8) and (':' not in problem_words2[0]) ):
            print problem_words2[0]+condition_String+"[index:"+real_index+"]" #DEBUG
            #Add a space to the next so that it doesnt join the lastW from this list and firstW from the next
            #Then Join this line and the next
            #Then replace word_list
            lines_list[index+1] = " "+lines_list[index+1]
            lines_list[index:index+2] = [''.join(lines_list[index:index+2])]
            word_list = lines_list[index].split()

    return word_list


#open the file
input_file = open( "/Users/carlosgarzon/Desktop/Projects/LearnHtml/Bereshit/BereshitPython/data_chapter1.txt", "r")

#read file into a list of lines
lines_list = input_file.read().splitlines()

# Close the File stream handler
input_file.close()

# The OPEN function returns a file object
write_file = open("/Users/carlosgarzon/Desktop/Projects/LearnHtml/Bereshit/BereshitPython/out_main_js.txt","w")

# Writing a VARIABLE to file in for loop
for index, var_list in enumerate(lines_list):

    #gltich: A string that does not beging where verse begins i.e genesis 1:7

    #tric for splitin a string to a list of words
    #This will be used if nothing was a glitch
    word_list = var_list.split()

    #get number of words in this verse
    num_word_lists = len(lines_list)

    #If current and next string is a glitch just join current with previous
    if ( (word_list[0].isdigit() < 8) and (':' not in word_list[0]) ) and concatenateNext_string_TF( index, lines_list):
        word_list = concatenateNext_string( index - 1, lines_list, "[cur&nextGlitch]", str(index) )
    #Catches if NEXT string is a glitch 
    if concatenateNext_string_TF( index, lines_list):
        word_list = concatenateNext_string( index, lines_list, "[nextGlitch]", str(index) )
    #If current string is a glitch join it to previous
    elif ( (word_list[0].isdigit() < 8) and (':' not in word_list[0]) ):
        word_list = concatenateNext_string( index - 1, lines_list, "[curGlitch]", str(index) )

    #not including C:V and starting on 0 index
    num_words = len(word_list) - 1

    for index2, word in enumerate(word_list):
        if len(word_list) > 1:
            #Bad Data: References, Page Title, (c) 
            if ( index2 == 0 and word.isdigit() ) or ( word_list[0] == 'The' and word_list[1] == 'Mechanical' ) or ( word_list[1] == 'Jeff' ):
                print "Bad Data"
                break

        #DEBUG: we found a new verse. It's printing the index of the outer for loop not this one
        if ':' in word:
            print word+ "  " + word_list[1]+"("+str(index)+")"+"\n"

        write_file.write(word+"("+str(index2)+")")

    #exit inner for loop        
    write_file.write("NumWordsInVerse("+str(num_words)+")"+"\n")

# Close the FILE object in PYTHON
write_file.close
```

Here is the file that I'm reading from. Note how new lines are sometimes in the middle of verses. The output file, that I'll show next eliminates these glitches. Problem is, in the output file I notice data completely skips over verse 1:6 and verse 1:23.

This is the file that I'm reading from. I condensed it a bit and replaced those parts with ......

```
    1:1 in~SUMMIT 2363 בְּרֵאשִׁית bê'rey'shit he~did~FATTEN(V) 232 בָּרָּא ba'ra Elohiym POWER~s אֱלֹהִׁים e'lo'him AT 85 אֵת eyt the~SKY 2512~s2 הַשָּמַיִׁם ha'sha'ma'yim and~AT 85 וְּאֵת wê'eyt the~LAND 2331 הָּאָרֶץ ha'a'rets
1:2 and~the~LAND 2331 וְּהָּאָרֶץ wê'ha'a'rets she~did~EXIST(V) 505 הָּיְּתָּה hai'tah CONFUSION 2623 תֹהוּ to'hu and~UNFILLED 106 וָּבֹהוּ wa'vo'hu and~DARKNESS 2439 וְּחֹשֶךְ wê'hho'shekh UPON 1616 עַל al FACE 1815~s פְּנֵי pê'ney DEEP.SEA 522 תְּהוֹם tê'hom and~WIND 2251 וְּרוּחַַ wê'ru'ahh Elohiym POWER~s אֱלֹהִׁים e'lo'him much~FLUTTER(V) 787~ing(fs) מְּרַחֶפֶת mê'ra'hhe'phet UPON 1616 עַל al FACE 1815~s פְּנֵי pê'ney the~WATER 1162~s2 הַמָּיִׁם ha'ma'yim
1:3 and~he~will~SAY(V) 1187 וַיֹאמֶר wai'yo'mer Elohiym POWER~s אֱלֹהִׁים e'lo'him he~will~EXIST(V) 505 יְּהִׁי yê'hi LIGHT 73 אוֹר
or and~he~will~EXIST(V) 505 וַיְּהִׁי wai'hi LIGHT 73 אוֹר or
1:4 and~he~will~SEE(V) 2185 וַיַרְּא wai'yar Elohiym POWER~s אֱלֹהִׁים e'lo'him AT 85 אֶת et the~LIGHT 73 הָּאוֹר ha'or GIVEN.THAT 940 כִׁי ki FUNCTIONAL 848 טוֹב tov and~he~will~make~SEPARATE(V) 100 וַיַבְּדֵל wai'yav'deyl Elohiym POWER~s אֱלֹהִׁים e'lo'him BETWEEN 193 בֵין beyn the~LIGHT 73 הָּאוֹר ha'or and~BETWEEN 193 וּבֵין u'veyn the~DARKNESS 2439 הַחֹשֶךְ ha'hho'shekh
1:5 and~he~will~CALL.OUT(V) 2147 וַיִׁקְּרָּא wai'yiq'ra Elohiym POWER~s אֱלֹהִׁים e'lo'him to~LIGHT 73 לָּאוֹר la'or DAY 898 יוֹם
yom and~to~DARKNESS 2439 וְּלַחֹשֶךְ wê'la'hho'shekh he~did~CALL.OUT(V) 2147 קָּרָּא qa'ra NIGHT 1111 לָּיְּלָּה lai'lah and~he~will~EXIST(V) 505 וַיְּהִׁי wai'hi EVENING 2724 עֶרֶב e'rev and~he~will~EXIST(V) 505 וַיְּהִׁי wai'hi MORNING 1861 בֹקֶר
vo'qer DAY 898 יוֹם yom UNIT 636 אֶחָּד e'hhad
1:6 and~he~will~SAY(V) 1187 וַיֹאמֶר wai'yo'mer Elohiym POWER~s אֱלֹהִׁים e'lo'him he~will~EXIST(V) 505 יְּהִׁי yê'hi SHEET 2118 רָּקִׁיעַַ ra'qi'a in~MIDST 2631 בְּתוֹךְ bê'tokh the~WATER 1162~s2 הַמָּיִׁם ha'ma'yim and~he~will~EXIST(V) 505 וִׁיהִׁי wi'hi make~SEPARATE(V) 100~ing(ms) מַבְּדִׁיל mav'dil BETWEEN 193 בֵין beyn WATER 1162~s2 מַיִׁם ma'yim to~WATER 1162~s2 לָּמָּיִׁם la'ma'yim
1:7 and~he~will~DO(V) 1686 וַיַעַשׂ wai'ya'as Elohiym POWER~s אֱלֹהִׁים e'lo'him AT 85 אֶת et the~SHEET 2118 הָּרָּקִׁיעַַ ha'ra'qi'a and~he~will~make~SEPARATE(V) 100 וַיַבְּדֵל wai'yav'deyl BETWEEN 193 בֵין beyn the~WATER 1162~s2 הַמַיִׁם ha'ma'yim WHICH 2589 אֲשֶר a'sher from~UNDER 2627 מִׁתַחַת mi'ta'hhat to~SHEET 2118 לָּרָּקִׁיעַַ la'ra'qi'a and~BETWEEN 193 וּבֵין
u'veyn the~WATER 1162~s2 הַמַיִׁם ha'ma'yim WHICH 2589 אֲשֶר a'sher from~UPON 1616 מֵעַל mey'al to~SHEET 2118 לָּרָּקִׁיעַַ
la'ra'qi'a and~he~will~EXIST(V) 505 וַיְּהִׁי wai'hi SO 968 כֵן kheyn2
1:8 and~he~will~CALL.OUT(V) 2147 וַיִׁקְּרָּא wai'yiq'ra Elohiym POWER~s אֱלֹהִׁים e'lo'him to~SHEET 2118 לָּרָּקִׁיעַַ la'ra'qi'a SKY 2512~s2 שָּמָּיִׁם sha'ma'yim and~he~will~EXIST(V) 505 וַיְּהִׁי wai'hi EVENING 2724 עֶרֶב e'rev and~he~will~EXIST(V) 505 וַיְּהִׁי
wai'hi MORNING 1861 בֹקֶר vo'qer DAY 898 יוֹם yom SECOND 2541 שֵנִׁי shey'ni
1:9 and~he~will~SAY(V) 1187 וַיֹאמֶר wai'yo'mer Elohiym POWER~s אֱלֹהִׁים e'lo'him he~will~be~BOUND.UP(V) 2060 יִׁקָּווּ
yi'qaw'u the~WATER 1162~s2 הַמַיִׁם ha'ma'yim from~UNDER 2627 מִׁתַחַת mi'ta'hhat the~SKY 2512~s2 הַשָּמַיִׁם
ha'sha'ma'yim TO 26 אֶל el AREA 2092 מָּקוֹם ma'qom UNIT 636 אֶחָּד e'hhad and~she~be~SEE(V) 2185 וְּתֵרָּאֶה wê'tey'ra'eh the~DRY.GROUND 258 הַיַבָּשָּה hai'ya'ba'shah and~he~will~EXIST(V) 505 וַיְּהִׁי wai'hi SO 968 כֵן kheyn3
1:10 and~he~will~CALL.OUT(V) 2147 וַיִׁקְּרָּא wai'yiq'ra Elohiym POWER~s אֱלֹהִׁים e'lo'him to~DRY.GROUND 258 לַיַבָּשָּה
lai'ya'ba'shah LAND 2331 אֶרֶץ e'rets and~to~COLLECTION 2061 וּלְּמִׁקְּוֵה ul'miq'weh the~WATER 1162~s2 הַמַיִׁם ha'ma'yim he~did~CALL.OUT(V) 2147 קָּרָּא qa'ra SEA 895~s יַמִׁים ya'mim and~he~will~SEE(V) 2185 וַיַרְּא wai'yar Elohiym POWER~s אֱלֹהִׁים
e'lo'him GIVEN.THAT 940 כִׁי ki FUNCTIONAL 848 טוֹב tov
1 The skies and land are "fattened" In the sense of being "filled up."
2 The phrase "and he will exist so" means "and it is firmly established."
3 The phrase "and he will exist so" means "and it is firmly established."
The Mechanical Translation of the Torah The Book of Genesis
© Jeff A. Benner Page 3 www.mechanical-translation.org
............................................
1:22 and~he~will~much~KNEEL(V) 236 וַיְּבָּרֶךְ wai'va'rekh AT 85~them(mp) אֹתָּם o'tam Elohiym POWER~s אֱלֹהִׁים e'lo'him to~>~SAY(V) 1187 לֵאמֹר ley'mor !(mp)~REPRODUCE(V) 1858 פְּרוּ pê'ru and~!(mp)~INCREASE(V) 2197 וּרְּבוּ ur'vu and~!(mp)~FILL(V) 1192 וּמִׁלְּאוּ u'mil'u AT 85 אֶת et the~WATER 1162~s2 הַמַיִׁם ha'ma'yim in~the~SEA 895~s בַיַמִׁים
ba'ya'mim and~the~FLYER 1701 וְּהָּעוֹף wê'ha'oph he~did~INCREASE(V) 2197 יִׁרֶב yi'rev in~the~LAND 2331 בָּאָרֶץ ba'a'rets
1:23 and~he~will~EXIST(V) 505 וַיְּהִׁי wai'hi EVENING 2724 עֶרֶב e'rev and~he~will~EXIST(V) 505 וַיְּהִׁי wai'hi MORNING 1861 בֹקֶר vo'qer DAY 898 יוֹם yom FIFTH 1271 חֲמִׁישִׁי hha'mi'shi
1:24 and~he~will~SAY(V) 1187 וַיֹאמֶר wai'yo'mer Elohiym POWER~s אֱלֹהִׁים e'lo'him she~will~make~GO.OUT(V) 1922 תוֹצֵא
to'tsey the~LAND 2331 הָּאָרֶץ ha'a'rets BEING 1902 נֶפֶש ne'phesh LIVING 667 חַיָּה hhai'yah to~KIND 1216~her לְּמִׁינָּהּ
lê'mi'nah BEAST 178 בְּהֵמָּה bê'hey'mah and~TREADER 2313 וָּרֶמֶשׂ wa're'mes and~LIVING 667~him וְּחַיְּתוַֹ wê'hhai'to2 LAND 2331 אֶרֶץ e'rets to~KIND 1216~her לְּמִׁינָּהּ lê'mi'nah and~he~will~EXIST(V) 505 וַיְּהִׁי wai'hi SO 968 כֵן kheyn3
1:25 and~he~will~DO(V) 1686 וַיַעַשׂ wai'ya'as Elohiym POWER~s אֱלֹהִׁים e'lo'him AT 85 אֶת et LIVING 667 חַיַת hhai'yat the~LAND 2331 הָּאָרֶץ ha'a'rets to~KIND 1216~her לְּמִׁינָּהּ lê'mi'nah and~AT 85 וְּאֶת wê'et the~BEAST 178 הַבְּהֵמָּה
ha'be'hey'mah to~KIND 1216~her לְּמִׁינָּהּ lê'mi'nah and~AT 85 וְּאֵת wê'eyt ALL 957 כָּל kol TREADER 2313 רֶמֶשׂ re'mes the~GROUND 425 הָּאֲדָּמָּה ha'a'da'mah to~KIND 1216~him לְּמִׁינֵהוּ lê'mi'ney'hu and~he~will~SEE(V) 2185 וַיַרְּא wai'yar Elohiym POWER~s אֱלֹהִׁים e'lo'him GIVEN.THAT 940 כִׁי ki FUNCTIONAL 848 טוֹב tov
1:26 and~he~will~SAY(V) 1187 וַיֹאמֶר wai'yo'mer Elohiym POWER~s אֱלֹהִׁים e'lo'him we(cp)~will~DO(V) 1686 נַעֲשֶׂה na'a'seh HUMAN 424 אָדָּם a'dam in~IMAGE 1971~us(cp) בְּצַלְּמֵנוּ bê'tsal'mey'nu like~LIKENESS 431~us(cp) כִׁדְּמוּתֵנוּ kid'mu'tey'nu and~he~did~RULE(V) 2235 וְּיִׁרְּדוּ wê'yir'du in~FISH 395 בִׁדְּגַת vid'gat the~SEA 895 הַיָּם hai'yam and~in~FLYER 1701 וּבְּעוֹף
uv'oph the~SKY 2512~s2 הַשָּמַיִׁם ha'sha'ma'yim and~in~the~BEAST 178 וּבַבְּהֵמָּה u'va'be'hey'mah and~in~ALL 957 וּבְּכָּל
uv'khol the~LAND 2331 הָּאָרֶץ ha'a'rets and~in~ALL 957 וּבְּכָּל uv'khol the~TREADER 2313 הָּרֶמֶשׂ ha're'mes the~TREAD(V) 2312~ing(ms) הָּרֹמֵשׂ ha'ro'meys UPON 1616 עַל al the~LAND 2331 הָּאָרֶץ ha'a'rets
1:27 and~he~will~FATTEN(V) 232 וַיִׁבְּרָּא wai'yiv'ra Elohiym POWER~s אֱלֹהִׁים e'lo'him AT 85 אֶת et the~HUMAN 424 הָּאָדָּם
ha'a'dam in~IMAGE 1971~him בְּצַלְּמוַֹ bê'tsal'mo in~IMAGE 1971 בְּצֶלֶם bê'tse'lem Elohiym POWER~s אֱלֹהִׁים e'lo'him
1 This Hebrew word is translated in various ways including; whale, sea-monster, dragon, serpent, asp and jackal (see Exodus 7:9, Deuteronomy 32:33, Nehemiah 2:13, Job 7:12). According to these texts this is a very large creature and lives on the land and in the water, which are charecteristics of the crocodile.
2 The Hebrew literally reads "his living ones," but may be written defectively.
3 The phrase "and he existed so" Hebraicly means "and it is firmly established."
The Mechanical Translation of the Torah The Book of Genesis
© Jeff A. Benner Page 5 www.mechanical-translation.org
he~did~FATTEN(V) 232 בָּרָּא ba'ra AT 85~him אֹתוַֹ o'to MALE 1024 זָּכָּר za'khar and~FEMALE 2043 וּנְּקֵבָּה un'qey'vah he~did~FATTEN(V) 232 בָּרָּא ba'ra AT 85~them(mp) אֹתָּם o'tam
1:28 and~he~will~much~KNEEL(V) 236 וַיְּבָּרֶךְ wai'va'rekh AT 85~them(mp) אֹתָּם o'tam Elohiym POWER~s אֱלֹהִׁים e'lo'him and~he~will~SAY(V) 1187 וַיֹאמֶר wai'yo'mer to~them(mp) לָּהֶם la'hem Elohiym POWER~s אֱלֹהִׁים e'lo'him !(mp)~REPRODUCE(V) 1858 פְּרוּ pê'ru and~!(mp)~INCREASE(V) 2197 וּרְּבוּ ur'vu and~!(mp)~FILL(V) 1192 וּמִׁלְּאוּ u'mil'u AT 85 אֶת
et the~LAND 2331 הָּאָרֶץ ha'a'rets and~!(mp)~SUBDUE(V) 205~her וְּכִׁבְּשֻׁהַָּ wê'khiv'shu'ah and~!(mp)~RULE(V) 2235 וּרְּדוּ
ur'du in~FISH 395 בִׁדְּגַת bid'gat the~SEA 895 הַיָּם hai'yam and~in~FLYER 1701 וּבְּעוֹף uv'oph the~SKY 2512~s2 הַשָּמַיִׁם
ha'sha'ma'yim and~in~ALL 957 וּבְּכָּל uv'khol LIVING 667 חַיָּה hhai'yah the~TREAD(V) 2312~ing(fs) הָּרֹמֶשֶׂת ha'ro'me'set UPON 1616 עַל al the~LAND 2331 הָּאָרֶץ ha'a'rets
1:29 and~he~will~SAY(V) 1187 וַיֹאמֶר wai'yo'mer Elohiym POWER~s אֱלֹהִׁים e'lo'him LOOK 526 הִׁנֵה hin'neyh I(cs)~did~GIVE(V) 2659 נָּתַתִׁי na'ta'ti to~you(mp) לָּכֶם la'khem AT 85 אֶת et ALL 957 כָּל kol HERB 1691 עֵשֶׂב ey'sev SOW(V) 605~ing(ms) זֹרֵעַַ zo'rey'a SEED 606 זֶרַע ze'ra WHICH 2589 אֲשֶר a'sher UPON 1616 עַל al FACE 1815~s פְּנֵי pê'ney ALL 957 כָּל khol the~LAND 2331 הָּאָרֶץ ha'a'rets and~AT 85 וְּאֶת wê'et ALL 957 כָּל kol the~TREE 1706 הָּעֵץ ha'eyts WHICH 2589 אֲשֶר a'sher in~him בוַֹ bo PRODUCE 1859 פְּרִׁי phê'ri TREE 1706 עֵץ eyts SOW(V) 605~ing(ms) זֹרֵעַַ zo'rey'a SEED 606 זָּרַע za'ra to~you(mp) לָּכֶם la'khem he~will~EXIST(V) 505 יִׁהְּיֶה yih'yeh to~FOOD 949 לְּאָכְּלָּה lê'akh'lah
1:30 and~to~ALL 957 וּלְּכָּל ul'khol LIVING 667 חַיַת hhai'yat the~LAND 2331 הָּאָרֶץ ha'a'rets and~to~ALL 957 וּלְּכָּל ul'khol FLYER 1701 עוֹף oph the~SKY 2512~s2 הַשָּמַיִׁם ha'sha'ma'yim and~to~ALL 957 וּלְּכֹל ul'khol TREAD(V) 2312~ing(ms) רוֹמֵשׂ
ro'meys UPON 1616 עַל al the~LAND 2331 הָּאָרֶץ ha'a'rets WHICH 2589 אֲשֶר a'sher in~him בוַֹ bo BEING 1902 נֶפֶש ne'phesh LIVING 667 חַיָּה hhai'yah AT 85 אֶת et ALL 957 כָּל kol GREEN 2349 יֶרֶק ye'req HERB 1691 עֵשֶׂב ey'sev to~FOOD 949 לְּאָכְּלָּה
lê'akh'lah and~he~will~EXIST(V) 505 וַיְּהִׁי wai'hi SO 968 כֵן kheyn1
1:31 and~he~will~SEE(V) 2185 וַיַרְּא wai'yar Elohiym POWER~s אֱלֹהִׁים e'lo'him AT 85 אֶת et ALL 957 כָּל kol WHICH 2589 אֲשֶר
a'sher he~did~DO(V) 1686 עָּשָּׂה a'sah and~LOOK 526 וְּהִׁנֵה wê'hin'neyh FUNCTIONAL 848 טוֹב tov MANY 8 מְּאֹד mê'od and~he~will~EXIST(V) 505 וַיְּהִׁי wai'hi EVENING 2724 עֶרֶב e'rev and~he~will~EXIST(V) 505 וַיְּהִׁי wai'hi MORNING 1861 בֹקֶר
vo'qer DAY 898 יוֹם yom the~SIXTH 2613 הַשִׁשִׁי ha'shi'shi2
```

Here is the output. The main problem is that v 1:6 and v 1:23 is being completely skipped over. I want to find out why this is and how to fix it.

Here is the output file. I condensed it a bit and replaced those parts with ......

```
    1:1(0)in~SUMMIT(1)2363(2)בְּרֵאשִׁית(3)bê'rey'shit(4)he~did~FATTEN(V)(5)232(6)בָּרָּא(7)ba'ra(8)Elohiym(9)POWER~s(10)אֱלֹהִׁים(11)e'lo'him(12)AT(13)85(14)אֵת(15)eyt(16)the~SKY(17)2512~s2(18)הַשָּמַיִׁם(19)ha'sha'ma'yim(20)and~AT(21)85(22)וְּאֵת(23)wê'eyt(24)the~LAND(25)2331(26)הָּאָרֶץ(27)ha'a'rets(28)NumWordsInVerse(28)
    1:2(0)and~the~LAND(1)2331(2)וְּהָּאָרֶץ(3)wê'ha'a'rets(4)she~did~EXIST(V)(5)505(6)הָּיְּתָּה(7)hai'tah(8)CONFUSION(9)2623(10)תֹהוּ(11)to'hu(12)and~UNFILLED(13)106(14)וָּבֹהוּ(15)wa'vo'hu(16)and~DARKNESS(17)2439(18)וְּחֹשֶךְ(19)wê'hho'shekh(20)UPON(21)1616(22)עַל(23)al(24)FACE(25)1815~s(26)פְּנֵי(27)pê'ney(28)DEEP.SEA(29)522(30)תְּהוֹם(31)tê'hom(32)and~WIND(33)2251(34)וְּרוּחַַ(35)wê'ru'ahh(36)Elohiym(37)POWER~s(38)אֱלֹהִׁים(39)e'lo'him(40)much~FLUTTER(V)(41)787~ing(fs)(42)מְּרַחֶפֶת(43)mê'ra'hhe'phet(44)UPON(45)1616(46)עַל(47)al(48)FACE(49)1815~s(50)פְּנֵי(51)pê'ney(52)the~WATER(53)1162~s2(54)הַמָּיִׁם(55)ha'ma'yim(56)NumWordsInVerse(56)
    1:3(0)and~he~will~SAY(V)(1)1187(2)וַיֹאמֶר(3)wai'yo'mer(4)Elohiym(5)POWER~s(6)אֱלֹהִׁים(7)e'lo'him(8)he~will~EXIST(V)(9)505(10)יְּהִׁי(11)yê'hi(12)LIGHT(13)73(14)אוֹר(15)or(16)and~he~will~EXIST(V)(17)505(18)וַיְּהִׁי(19)wai'hi(20)LIGHT(21)73(22)אוֹר(23)or(24)NumWordsInVerse(24)
    1:4(0)and~he~will~SEE(V)(1)2185(2)וַיַרְּא(3)wai'yar(4)Elohiym(5)POWER~s(6)אֱלֹהִׁים(7)e'lo'him(8)AT(9)85(10)אֶת(11)et(12)the~LIGHT(13)73(14)הָּאוֹר(15)ha'or(16)GIVEN.THAT(17)940(18)כִׁי(19)ki(20)FUNCTIONAL(21)848(22)טוֹב(23)tov(24)and~he~will~make~SEPARATE(V)(25)100(26)וַיַבְּדֵל(27)wai'yav'deyl(28)Elohiym(29)POWER~s(30)אֱלֹהִׁים(31)e'lo'him(32)BETWEEN(33)193(34)בֵין(35)beyn(36)the~LIGHT(37)73(38)הָּאוֹר(39)ha'or(40)and~BETWEEN(41)193(42)וּבֵין(43)u'veyn(44)the~DARKNESS(45)2439(46)הַחֹשֶךְ(47)ha'hho'shekh(48)NumWordsInVerse(48)
    1:5(0)and~he~will~CALL.OUT(V)(1)2147(2)וַיִׁקְּרָּא(3)wai'yiq'ra(4)Elohiym(5)POWER~s(6)אֱלֹהִׁים(7)e'lo'him(8)to~LIGHT(9)73(10)לָּאוֹר(11)la'or(12)DAY(13)898(14)יוֹם(15)yom(16)and~to~DARKNESS(17)2439(18)וְּלַחֹשֶךְ(19)wê'la'hho'shekh(20)he~did~CALL.OUT(V)(21)2147(22)קָּרָּא(23)qa'ra(24)NIGHT(25)1111(26)לָּיְּלָּה(27)lai'lah(28)and~he~will~EXIST(V)(29)505(30)וַיְּהִׁי(31)wai'hi(32)EVENING(33)2724(34)עֶרֶב(35)e'rev(36)and~he~will~EXIST(V)(37)505(38)וַיְּהִׁי(39)wai'hi(40)MORNING(41)1861(42)בֹקֶר(43)NumWordsInVerse(43)
    1:5(0)and~he~will~CALL.OUT(V)(1)2147(2)וַיִׁקְּרָּא(3)wai'yiq'ra(4)Elohiym(5)POWER~s(6)אֱלֹהִׁים(7)e'lo'him(8)to~LIGHT(9)73(10)לָּאוֹר(11)la'or(12)DAY(13)898(14)יוֹם(15)yom(16)and~to~DARKNESS(17)2439(18)וְּלַחֹשֶךְ(19)wê'la'hho'shekh(20)he~did~CALL.OUT(V)(21)2147(22)קָּרָּא(23)qa'ra(24)NIGHT(25)1111(26)לָּיְּלָּה(27)lai'lah(28)and~he~will~EXIST(V)(29)505(30)וַיְּהִׁי(31)wai'hi(32)EVENING(33)2724(34)עֶרֶב(35)e'rev(36)and~he~will~EXIST(V)(37)505(38)וַיְּהִׁי(39)wai'hi(40)MORNING(41)1861(42)בֹקֶר(43)vo'qer(44)DAY(45)898(46)יוֹם(47)yom(48)UNIT(49)636(50)אֶחָּד(51)e'hhad(52)NumWordsInVerse(52)
    1:7(0)and~he~will~DO(V)(1)1686(2)וַיַעַשׂ(3)wai'ya'as(4)Elohiym(5)POWER~s(6)אֱלֹהִׁים(7)e'lo'him(8)AT(9)85(10)אֶת(11)et(12)the~SHEET(13)2118(14)הָּרָּקִׁיעַַ(15)ha'ra'qi'a(16)and~he~will~make~SEPARATE(V)(17)100(18)וַיַבְּדֵל(19)wai'yav'deyl(20)BETWEEN(21)193(22)בֵין(23)beyn(24)the~WATER(25)1162~s2(26)הַמַיִׁם(27)ha'ma'yim(28)WHICH(29)2589(30)אֲשֶר(31)a'sher(32)from~UNDER(33)2627(34)מִׁתַחַת(35)mi'ta'hhat(36)to~SHEET(37)2118(38)לָּרָּקִׁיעַַ(39)la'ra'qi'a(40)and~BETWEEN(41)193(42)וּבֵין(43)u'veyn(44)the~WATER(45)1162~s2(46)הַמַיִׁם(47)ha'ma'yim(48)WHICH(49)2589(50)אֲשֶר(51)a'sher(52)from~UPON(53)1616(54)מֵעַל(55)mey'al(56)to~SHEET(57)2118(58)לָּרָּקִׁיעַַ(59)NumWordsInVerse(59)
    1:7(0)and~he~will~DO(V)(1)1686(2)וַיַעַשׂ(3)wai'ya'as(4)Elohiym(5)POWER~s(6)אֱלֹהִׁים(7)e'lo'him(8)AT(9)85(10)אֶת(11)et(12)the~SHEET(13)2118(14)הָּרָּקִׁיעַַ(15)ha'ra'qi'a(16)and~he~will~make~SEPARATE(V)(17)100(18)וַיַבְּדֵל(19)wai'yav'deyl(20)BETWEEN(21)193(22)בֵין(23)beyn(24)the~WATER(25)1162~s2(26)הַמַיִׁם(27)ha'ma'yim(28)WHICH(29)2589(30)אֲשֶר(31)a'sher(32)from~UNDER(33)2627(34)מִׁתַחַת(35)mi'ta'hhat(36)to~SHEET(37)2118(38)לָּרָּקִׁיעַַ(39)la'ra'qi'a(40)and~BETWEEN(41)193(42)וּבֵין(43)u'veyn(44)the~WATER(45)1162~s2(46)הַמַיִׁם(47)ha'ma'yim(48)WHICH(49)2589(50)אֲשֶר(51)a'sher(52)from~UPON(53)1616(54)מֵעַל(55)mey'al(56)to~SHEET(57)2118(58)לָּרָּקִׁיעַַ(59)la'ra'qi'a(60)and~he~will~EXIST(V)(61)505(62)וַיְּהִׁי(63)wai'hi(64)SO(65)968(66)כֵן(67)kheyn2(68)NumWordsInVerse(68)
..............................
    1:19(0)and~he~will~EXIST(V)(1)505(2)וַיְּהִׁי(3)wai'hi(4)EVENING(5)2724(6)עֶרֶב(7)e'rev(8)and~he~will~EXIST(V)(9)505(10)וַיְּהִׁי(11)wai'hi(12)MORNING(13)1861(14)בֹקֶר(15)vo'qer(16)DAY(17)898(18)יוֹם(19)yom(20)FOURTH(21)2214(22)רְּבִׁיעִׁי(23)rê'vi'i(24)NumWordsInVerse(24)
    1:20(0)and~he~will~SAY(V)(1)1187(2)וַיֹאמֶר(3)wai'yo'mer(4)Elohiym(5)POWER~s(6)אֱלֹהִׁים(7)e'lo'him(8)they(mp)~will~SWARM(V)(9)2341(10)יִׁשְּרְּצוּ(11)yish're'tsu(12)the~WATER(13)1162~s2(14)הַמַיִׁם(15)ha'ma'yim(16)SWARMER(17)2342(18)שֶרֶץ(19)she'rets(20)BEING(21)1902(22)נֶפֶש(23)ne'phesh(24)LIVING(25)667(26)חַיָּה(27)NumWordsInVerse(27)
    1:20(0)and~he~will~SAY(V)(1)1187(2)וַיֹאמֶר(3)wai'yo'mer(4)Elohiym(5)POWER~s(6)אֱלֹהִׁים(7)e'lo'him(8)they(mp)~will~SWARM(V)(9)2341(10)יִׁשְּרְּצוּ(11)yish're'tsu(12)the~WATER(13)1162~s2(14)הַמַיִׁם(15)ha'ma'yim(16)SWARMER(17)2342(18)שֶרֶץ(19)she'rets(20)BEING(21)1902(22)נֶפֶש(23)ne'phesh(24)LIVING(25)667(26)חַיָּה(27)hhai'yah(28)and~FLYER(29)1701(30)וְּעוֹף(31)wê'oph(32)he~will~much~FLY(V)(33)1700(34)יְּעוֹפֵף(35)yê'o'pheyph(36)UPON(37)1616(38)עַל(39)al(40)the~LAND(41)2331(42)הָּאָרֶץ(43)NumWordsInVerse(43)
    1:21(0)and~he~will~FATTEN(V)(1)232(2)וַיִׁבְּרָּא(3)wai'yiv'ra(4)Elohiym(5)POWER~s(6)אֱלֹהִׁים(7)e'lo'him(8)AT(9)85(10)אֶת(11)et(12)the~CROCODILE(13)2654~s(14)הַתַנִׁינִׁם(15)ha'ta'ni'nim1(16)the~GREAT(17)292~s(18)הַגְּדֹלִׁים(19)ha'ge'do'lim(20)and~AT(21)85(22)וְּאֵת(23)wê'eyt(24)ALL(25)957(26)כָּל(27)kol(28)BEING(29)1902(30)נֶפֶש(31)ne'phesh(32)the~LIVING(33)667(34)הַחַיָּה(35)ha'hha'yah(36)the~TREAD(V)(37)2312~ing(fs)(38)הָּרֹמֶשֶׂת(39)ha'ro'me'set(40)WHICH(41)2589(42)אֲשֶר(43)a'sher(44)they(mp)~did~SWARM(V)(45)2341(46)שָּרְּצוּ(47)shar'tsu(48)the~WATER(49)1162~s2(50)הַמַיִׁם(51)ha'ma'yim(52)to~KIND(53)1216~them(mp)(54)לְּמִׁינֵהֶם(55)NumWordsInVerse(55)
    1:21(0)and~he~will~FATTEN(V)(1)232(2)וַיִׁבְּרָּא(3)wai'yiv'ra(4)Elohiym(5)POWER~s(6)אֱלֹהִׁים(7)e'lo'him(8)AT(9)85(10)אֶת(11)et(12)the~CROCODILE(13)2654~s(14)הַתַנִׁינִׁם(15)ha'ta'ni'nim1(16)the~GREAT(17)292~s(18)הַגְּדֹלִׁים(19)ha'ge'do'lim(20)and~AT(21)85(22)וְּאֵת(23)wê'eyt(24)ALL(25)957(26)כָּל(27)kol(28)BEING(29)1902(30)נֶפֶש(31)ne'phesh(32)the~LIVING(33)667(34)הַחַיָּה(35)ha'hha'yah(36)the~TREAD(V)(37)2312~ing(fs)(38)הָּרֹמֶשֶׂת(39)ha'ro'me'set(40)WHICH(41)2589(42)אֲשֶר(43)a'sher(44)they(mp)~did~SWARM(V)(45)2341(46)שָּרְּצוּ(47)shar'tsu(48)the~WATER(49)1162~s2(50)הַמַיִׁם(51)ha'ma'yim(52)to~KIND(53)1216~them(mp)(54)לְּמִׁינֵהֶם(55)lê'mi'ney'hem(56)and~AT(57)85(58)וְּאֵת(59)wê'eyt(60)ALL(61)957(62)כָּל(63)kol(64)FLYER(65)1701(66)עוֹף(67)oph(68)WING(69)984(70)כָּנָּף(71)ka'naph(72)to~KIND(73)1216~him(74)לְּמִׁינֵהוּ(75)lê'mi'ney'hu(76)and~he~will~SEE(V)(77)2185(78)וַיַרְּא(79)wai'yar(80)Elohiym(81)POWER~s(82)אֱלֹהִׁים(83)e'lo'him(84)GIVEN.THAT(85)940(86)כִׁי(87)ki(88)FUNCTIONAL(89)848(90)טוֹב(91)tov(92)NumWordsInVerse(92)
    1:22(0)and~he~will~much~KNEEL(V)(1)236(2)וַיְּבָּרֶךְ(3)wai'va'rekh(4)AT(5)85~them(mp)(6)אֹתָּם(7)o'tam(8)Elohiym(9)POWER~s(10)אֱלֹהִׁים(11)e'lo'him(12)to~>~SAY(V)(13)1187(14)לֵאמֹר(15)ley'mor(16)!(mp)~REPRODUCE(V)(17)1858(18)פְּרוּ(19)pê'ru(20)and~!(mp)~INCREASE(V)(21)2197(22)וּרְּבוּ(23)ur'vu(24)and~!(mp)~FILL(V)(25)1192(26)וּמִׁלְּאוּ(27)u'mil'u(28)AT(29)85(30)אֶת(31)et(32)the~WATER(33)1162~s2(34)הַמַיִׁם(35)ha'ma'yim(36)in~the~SEA(37)895~s(38)בַיַמִׁים(39)ba'ya'mim(40)and~the~FLYER(41)1701(42)וְּהָּעוֹף(43)wê'ha'oph(44)he~did~INCREASE(V)(45)2197(46)יִׁרֶב(47)yi'rev(48)in~the~LAND(49)2331(50)בָּאָרֶץ(51)ba'a'rets(52)NumWordsInVerse(52)
    1:24(0)and~he~will~SAY(V)(1)1187(2)וַיֹאמֶר(3)wai'yo'mer(4)Elohiym(5)POWER~s(6)אֱלֹהִׁים(7)e'lo'him(8)she~will~make~GO.OUT(V)(9)1922(10)תוֹצֵא(11)to'tsey(12)the~LAND(13)2331(14)הָּאָרֶץ(15)ha'a'rets(16)BEING(17)1902(18)נֶפֶש(19)ne'phesh(20)LIVING(21)667(22)חַיָּה(23)hhai'yah(24)to~KIND(25)1216~her(26)לְּמִׁינָּהּ(27)NumWordsInVerse(27)
    1:24(0)and~he~will~SAY(V)(1)1187(2)וַיֹאמֶר(3)wai'yo'mer(4)Elohiym(5)POWER~s(6)אֱלֹהִׁים(7)e'lo'him(8)she~will~make~GO.OUT(V)(9)1922(10)תוֹצֵא(11)to'tsey(12)the~LAND(13)2331(14)הָּאָרֶץ(15)ha'a'rets(16)BEING(17)1902(18)נֶפֶש(19)ne'phesh(20)LIVING(21)667(22)חַיָּה(23)hhai'yah(24)to~KIND(25)1216~her(26)לְּמִׁינָּהּ(27)lê'mi'nah(28)BEAST(29)178(30)בְּהֵמָּה(31)bê'hey'mah(32)and~TREADER(33)2313(34)וָּרֶמֶשׂ(35)wa're'mes(36)and~LIVING(37)667~him(38)וְּחַיְּתוַֹ(39)wê'hhai'to2(40)LAND(41)2331(42)אֶרֶץ(43)e'rets(44)to~KIND(45)1216~her(46)לְּמִׁינָּהּ(47)lê'mi'nah(48)and~he~will~EXIST(V)(49)505(50)וַיְּהִׁי(51)wai'hi(52)SO(53)968(54)כֵן(55)kheyn3(56)NumWordsInVerse(56)
    1:25(0)and~he~will~DO(V)(1)1686(2)וַיַעַשׂ(3)wai'ya'as(4)Elohiym(5)POWER~s(6)אֱלֹהִׁים(7)e'lo'him(8)AT(9)85(10)אֶת(11)et(12)LIVING(13)667(14)חַיַת(15)hhai'yat(16)the~LAND(17)2331(18)הָּאָרֶץ(19)ha'a'rets(20)to~KIND(21)1216~her(22)לְּמִׁינָּהּ(23)lê'mi'nah(24)and~AT(25)85(26)וְּאֶת(27)wê'et(28)the~BEAST(29)178(30)הַבְּהֵמָּה(31)ha'be'hey'mah(32)to~KIND(33)1216~her(34)לְּמִׁינָּהּ(35)lê'mi'nah(36)and~AT(37)85(38)וְּאֵת(39)wê'eyt(40)ALL(41)957(42)כָּל(43)kol(44)TREADER(45)2313(46)רֶמֶשׂ(47)re'mes(48)the~GROUND(49)425(50)הָּאֲדָּמָּה(51)ha'a'da'mah(52)to~KIND(53)1216~him(54)לְּמִׁינֵהוּ(55)lê'mi'ney'hu(56)and~he~will~SEE(V)(57)2185(58)וַיַרְּא(59)wai'yar(60)Elohiym(61)POWER~s(62)אֱלֹהִׁים(63)e'lo'him(64)GIVEN.THAT(65)940(66)כִׁי(67)ki(68)FUNCTIONAL(69)848(70)טוֹב(71)tov(72)NumWordsInVerse(72)
    1:26(0)and~he~will~SAY(V)(1)1187(2)וַיֹאמֶר(3)wai'yo'mer(4)Elohiym(5)POWER~s(6)אֱלֹהִׁים(7)e'lo'him(8)we(cp)~will~DO(V)(9)1686(10)נַעֲשֶׂה(11)na'a'seh(12)HUMAN(13)424(14)אָדָּם(15)a'dam(16)in~IMAGE(17)1971~us(cp)(18)בְּצַלְּמֵנוּ(19)bê'tsal'mey'nu(20)like~LIKENESS(21)431~us(cp)(22)כִׁדְּמוּתֵנוּ(23)kid'mu'tey'nu(24)and~he~did~RULE(V)(25)2235(26)וְּיִׁרְּדוּ(27)wê'yir'du(28)in~FISH(29)395(30)בִׁדְּגַת(31)vid'gat(32)the~SEA(33)895(34)הַיָּם(35)hai'yam(36)and~in~FLYER(37)1701(38)וּבְּעוֹף(39)uv'oph(40)the~SKY(41)2512~s2(42)הַשָּמַיִׁם(43)ha'sha'ma'yim(44)and~in~the~BEAST(45)178(46)וּבַבְּהֵמָּה(47)u'va'be'hey'mah(48)and~in~ALL(49)957(50)וּבְּכָּל(51)NumWordsInVerse(51)
```

Here is my terminal output debug data, in case it helps

```
    1:1  in~SUMMIT(0)

1:2  and~the~LAND(1)

or[nextGlitch][index:2]
1:3  and~he~will~SAY(V)(2)

1:4  and~he~will~SEE(V)(3)

yom[nextGlitch][index:4]
1:5  and~he~will~CALL.OUT(V)(4)

vo'qer[curGlitch][index:5]
1:5  and~he~will~CALL.OUT(V)(5)

u'veyn[nextGlitch][index:6]
1:7  and~he~will~DO(V)(6)

la'ra'qi'a[curGlitch][index:7]
1:7  and~he~will~DO(V)(7)

wai'hi[curGlitch][index:8]
1:8  and~he~will~CALL.OUT(V)(8)

yi'qaw'u[cur&nextGlitch][index:9]
1:9  and~he~will~SAY(V)(9)

lai'ya'ba'shah[nextGlitch][index:10]
1:10  and~he~will~CALL.OUT(V)(10)

e'lo'him[cur&nextGlitch][index:11]
2[nextGlitch][index:11]
Bad Data
3[cur&nextGlitch][index:12]
©[nextGlitch][index:12]
Bad Data
tad'shey[nextGlitch][index:13]
1:11  and~he~will~SAY(V)(13)

maz'ri'a[cur&nextGlitch][index:14]
1:11  and~he~will~SAY(V)(14)

lê'mi'ney'hu[nextGlitch][index:15]
1:12  and~she~will~make~GO.OUT(V)(15)

1:13  and~he~will~EXIST(V)(16)

u'veyn[nextGlitch][index:17]
1:14  and~he~will~SAY(V)(17)

wê'sha'nim[curGlitch][index:18]
1:14  and~he~will~SAY(V)(18)

ha'a'rets[curGlitch][index:19]
1:15  and~they(cp)~did~EXIST(V)(19)

ha'ma'or[cur&nextGlitch][index:20]
1:16  and~he~will~DO(V)(20)

al[nextGlitch][index:21]
1:17  and~he~will~GIVE(V)(21)

e'lo'him[nextGlitch][index:22]
1:18  and~to~>~REGULATE(V)(22)

1[cur&nextGlitch][index:23]
3[nextGlitch][index:23]
Bad Data
4[cur&nextGlitch][index:24]
©[nextGlitch][index:24]
Bad Data
1:19  and~he~will~EXIST(V)(25)

yish're'tsu[nextGlitch][index:26]
1:20  and~he~will~SAY(V)(26)

hhai'yah[cur&nextGlitch][index:27]
1:20  and~he~will~SAY(V)(27)

ne'phesh[nextGlitch][index:28]
1:21  and~he~will~FATTEN(V)(28)

lê'mi'ney'hem[curGlitch][index:29]
1:21  and~he~will~FATTEN(V)(29)

ba'ya'mim[curGlitch][index:30]
1:22  and~he~will~much~KNEEL(V)(30)

to'tsey[nextGlitch][index:31]
1:24  and~he~will~SAY(V)(31)

lê'mi'nah[curGlitch][index:32]
1:24  and~he~will~SAY(V)(32)

ha'be'hey'mah[curGlitch][index:33]
1:25  and~he~will~DO(V)(33)

uv'oph[cur&nextGlitch][index:34]
1:26  and~he~will~SAY(V)(34)

ha'a'dam[nextGlitch][index:35]
1:27  and~he~will~FATTEN(V)(35)

1[cur&nextGlitch][index:36]
3[nextGlitch][index:36]
Bad Data
The[cur&nextGlitch][index:37]
he~did~FATTEN(V)[nextGlitch][index:37]
Bad Data
et[nextGlitch][index:38]
1:28  and~he~will~much~KNEEL(V)(38)

ur'du[cur&nextGlitch][index:39]
1:28  and~he~will~much~KNEEL(V)(39)

1:29  and~he~will~SAY(V)(40)

ro'meys[nextGlitch][index:41]
1:30  and~to~ALL(41)

lê'akh'lah[curGlitch][index:42]
1:30  and~to~ALL(42)

a'sher[cur&nextGlitch][index:43]
1:31  and~he~will~SEE(V)(43)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, partly because there's so much code/etc. Try to boil down the problem to the simplest possible example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing from you code that you are iterating and modifing the list at the same time, this will give you unexpected results. Use two lists, one for the data that you read from the file and another one for the new data. Have a look at this unrelated example:

```
>>> l = range(10)
>>> l
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> for i in l:
...   print(i)
...   x = l.pop()
... 
0
1
2
3
4
```

I have a couple of things to add:

Use the `with` keyword to open and close the file (both for reading and writing):

```
lines_list = None
with open('<your_file>') as handler:  # this will take care of closing the file for you
    lines_list = handler.read().splitlines()
```

Know when to use parenthesis, this:

```
if ( (word_list[0].isdigit() < 8) and (':' not in word_list[0]) ) and concatenateNext_string_TF( index, lines_list):
```

Is the same as:

```
if word_list[0].isdigit() < 8 and ':' not in word_list[0] and concatenateNext_string_TF(index, lines_list):
```